# How to import live site into localhost - DB size - 1.4GB & Root Folder Size - 1.2 GB

Tags: magento-1.9, database, import, sql, file-upload

I need to import my Live site into localhost for testing,

> DB size - 1.4GB & Root Folder Size - 1.2 GB

How can I import large size of SQL file into DB?

DB Import Error: You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara :  My issue regard importing not exporting.

Answer (score 0):

Please compress the database in sql.gz format :

```
mysqldump -u(username) -p(pwd) | gzip > testname.sql.gz
```

Comment: after compressed how to import?

Comment: after compressing of sql.gz format , you can import the database by the following query zcat filepath/test.sql.gz | mysql -u(username) -p(pwd) databasename

Comment: where i can run this query

Comment: what do you use ubuntu or windows

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: After compression what is the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps for large database import in local mysql server:

1. Open the command window.
2. Type the path of your mysql bin directory and press Enter.
3. Paste your SQL file inside the bin folder of mysql server.
4. Create a database in MySQL, for example **"testdb"**.
5. The run the below command:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p database_name < filenane.sql
   ```

   For example if database_name="testdb" ; filename= livedb.sql then command look like as shown below:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p testdb < livedb.sql
   ```

Comment: could you pls explain your point 2

Comment: mysql.exe directory path as /wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.9/bin for wamp sever.

Comment: mysql -u root -p testdb < livedb.sql   after this asked password, i can't give any password

Comment: just press enter if you do not have any password

Comment: after completion may i get ant success notification?

Comment: i get error message

Comment: no notification will come but if error occur you will nitified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60961/discussion-between-rathinam-and-prasanta-hatui).